# Package explorer displays folders that do not exist : <file contents not local>

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

The Eclipse package explorer displays folders that don't really exist.

I think this may be caused by file system and directories are not synchronized with workspace, so I use F5 to refresh this folder and project in order to keep them synchronized and I also use Project > Clean & reBuild but, 
after that ,those folders still remain existing.

Precondition : 
those folders are created with Plug-in Development APIs like IResource, IProject and IFolder ...

So in what condition this strange issue may happen?

[image]

Comment: I think you will get properties like this if the resource is a 'phantom' - something that has been deleted locally but still exists on a server (such as a source control repository). Look at `IResource.isPhantom()`

Comment: @greg-449 `IResource.isPhantom()` returns false.